# How to change the application that opens by mailto

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an application where the user can send and receive emails, like gmail, outlook.

But when the user clicks on <a href=mailto:"mail">, a native Windows application opens.

Compared to gmail, the same 'mailto' ref opens its own email sending function.

How can I change the mailto call to a function I created ?

Some changes:

The application created was made in "electron";
Setting the app as default on Windows isn't an option, as gmail on Chrome doesn't mind and opens its own function.

Edit: pseudo-solution

What I could do is edit the html that the API returns me containing the email and replace the href mailto (String.replace) with a function of mine.
But that's not what gmail uses, and I don't think it's the efficient way.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that other mail application set as the default mail application for that user's machine/system?

Comment: You can not change it with code. They are just capturing the links and saying to load it in their app.

Comment: the application was made in "electron", and despite not being the default, I don't know if that's the problem, because gmail in chrome opens its own function without being defined in windows.

Comment: Are you talking about mailto links clicked within the electron app?

Comment: yes, <a href="mailto:"mail...""></a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions here about what you're trying to do and where you're trying to do it, but…

You could [query for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) `mailto` links and attach an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) that cancels the default action (opening the default mail app) and then do whatever you need to do.

If you have lots of links you might want to take a more efficient approach to attaching the listener (e.g. attach at document root and query the event to see if it's an email link), but here's a quick proof-of-concept:

```js
function emailHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // do whatever you need to do...
  console.log(e.target.href);
}

document.querySelectorAll('[href^=mailto]').forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', emailHandler));
```

```html
<a href="mailto:one@example.com">Email One</a>
<a href="mailto:two@example.com">Email Two</a>
<a href="mailto:three@example.com">Email Three</a>
```

---

If you wanted to handle them with a single listener (as opposed to attaching to every individual mailto link) you could listen for click events at the container element (body or whatever) and interrogate them as they come in:

```js
function clickHandler(e) {
  if (e.target.href?.startsWith?.('mailto')) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    // do whatever you need to do...
    console.log(e.target.href);
  }  
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
```

```html
<a href="mailto:one@example.com">Email One</a>
<a href="mailto:two@example.com">Email Two</a>
<a href="mailto:three@example.com">Email Three</a>
```

Comment: perfect my friend, but I must pay attention to performance. Since this is an html email body, there are sometimes multiple replicas of the conversation. I'll follow your tip, a single listener, thanks!